# TRAP keeps printing the same value lc3

Tags: printing, lc3, machine-code

So I am writing a program(in LC-3 ISA Machine Language though i'm not sure if this an actual name for the specific type of machine language code, it's just the best way that I can describe it. I am new to machine language programming so i'm not very familiar with the different types of machine language code) for an LC-3 in which I am displaying the amount of times that an letter shows up on a rhyme(poem) and a verse. I am supposed to make the program such that it could print the amount of times a letter showed up(up to the number 99).

Everything is well, except for the last instruction, which is a TRAP x23(for printing). I used the trap instruction twice so that I could print out the two digits(which are acquired by dividing the count by 10 and storing the quotient and remainder into registers). Here is the code:

```
0011000000000000 ;pc starts here
0101010010100000 ;clear r2
0010101000100011 ; ld x3500 r5 
0010011000100000 ;ld x3012, r3
1111000000100011 ;trap in
0110001011000000 ;ldr r1, base r3(x3100), 
0001100001111100 ;r4 = r1 - 4, top of loop
0000010000001100 ;start loop check if r1 == 4(if it does, exit)
1001001001111111 ;NOT R1 and store in R1
0001001001100001 ;Add r1 + 1 and store in r1
0001001001000000 ;Add r1 + r0 and store in r1


0000101000000101 ;skip if r1 != 0
0001010010100001 ;r2++
0101110110000000 ;clear r6
0001110110000011 ;r6 = r6 + r3
0111110101000000 ;str r6 in the address r5 points to.
0001101101100001 ;increment r5 pointer.


0001011011100001 ;r3++(increment pointer)
0110001011000000 ;ldr into r1, content in the address r3 points to.
0000111111110010 ;GOTO TOP OF LOOP


;COUNT DIVISION
0101101100000000 ;clear r5
0001010010100000 ;r2 = r2(changes the flags for the upcoming loop).
0000110000000101 ;if r2 is <= 0, skip loop
0011010000001111 ; store r2 in PC + 15
0001010010110110 ;r2 = r2 - 10
0000110000000001 ; if r2 is negative or zero, skip the next instruction.
0001101101100001 ;r5++
0000111111111010 ;go to top of loop
0010010000001010 ;load value in PC + 10 to r2(remainder).


0010000000000111 ;LD into r0 x3014 
0001000000000101 ;Add r0 and x3013(ASCII character) store in r0
1111000000100001 ;trap print out quotient
0101000000100000 ;clear r0
0001000000000010 ; r0 = r0 + r2
1111000000100001 ;trap print out remainder.
1111000000100101 ;HALT

0011000100000000 ;data variables
0000000000110000
0011010100000000 ;x3500
```

Before I used register 0 to print out the remainder(in reg. 2), I only used it to print out the quotient and I used the following code to try to change the the value that was going to printed(I thought that TRAP x23 would print the value of the most recently called register):

```
0001010010100000 ;r2 = r2 + 0
```

But it only printed the quotient twice so I tried doing the following to see if anything would change:

```
0101001001100000 ;clear r1
0001001001000010 ;r1 = r1+r2
```

Nothing did. So I started to believe that TRAP x23 is printing out the values of only r0 so I changed the code to:

```
0101000000100000 ;clear r0
0001000000000010 ;r0 = r0 + r2
```

But the the console printed the quotient with an empty outlined box next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Trap x21 (OUT) ?  your code does not show Trap x23.  Trap x23 is IN which would read in a character not what you want here.

> Nothing did. So I started to believe that TRAP x23 is printing out the values of only r0 so I changed the code to:

Yes from the ISA document for TRAP *x21*

*OUT: Write a character in R0[7:0] to the console display.*

It will only print out the lower eight bits of R0.

> But the the console printed the quotient with an empty outlined box next to it.

Remember the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) if R0 contains 0 it will not print out a 0, but a NUL character from the table below.  If you want to print out a 0 then R0 must contain 48.  If you want to print a 1 then 49 and so on.